# Export vCF on a per contact basis

Tags: icloud, contacts

I am using Apple's Contacts app and I have hundreds of entries. Some are no longer valid (name change, incorrect phone, etc)

So I want to export them so I get 1 file per contact. This way, I can import them one at a time and work at each entry to make sure that it's correct. I also want to import them (one at a time) to my Microsoft Exchange account.

Comment: Why don't you edit the entries in place, in Contacts.app? Just curious.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is to use a Automator workflow.

The Contacts Actions provide the option for you to do what you want.

Example:
[image]

Just be aware that card will not export if the Name fields have for example a forwardd slash "**/**".  ( as I just discovered)